# How can I change the bottom border color for TextField when focus?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have a simple `TextField` :

[image]

How can I change  the blue color (*programmatically*) to another color  , when textfield is in focused ?

I've already accomplished partial solution :

```
  var v=this.page.getViewById< TextField>("a");
  var drawable = v.android.getBackground(); 
  drawable.setColorFilter(new Color("#b21755").android, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

*But When I navigate to another control , the red color remains :*

When It's in focus :

[image]

when It's out of focus : (red remains — I don't want that , I want the default color )

[image]

How can I make the color to back to its default color when moving out of focus ?

Comment: on lose focus, call clearColorFilter()

Comment: @dashman What can I say , you're the man . Works.

Comment: @dashman how about posting an answer and receiving your well-deserved reputation? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on lose focus, call clearColorFilter() .